# lodash implementation of return value === 0 ? value : 0

Tags: javascript, lodash

Can anyone explain why this line is used in lodash library.

```
if (!value) {
    return value === 0 ? value : 0;
}
```

and why not just return 0;

Comment: Can you point out where this line is, maybe a GitHub link or something?

Comment: https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/lodash.js#L11862

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two different values which are considered strictly equal to zero: `+0` and `-0`:

```
+0 === +0;
+0 === -0;
-0 === +0;
-0 === -0;
```

However, these values don't behave completely identically:

```
1 / +0 === +Infinity
1 / -0 === -Infinity
```

and clearly `+Infinity !== -Infinity`.

Then the code does this:

1. If `value` is "falsy" (`undefined`, `null`, `false`, `+0`, `-0`, `NaN`, `""`)

   1. If `value` is `+0` or `-0`, it returns `value`
   2. Otherwise, it returns `+0`

Comment: But when will `!value` be true but not `value === 0`?

Comment: @chepner: When `value` is `false`, `null`, etc